# How to split and transpose results over 2 columns

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Not sure how to even approach this.  How do I complete the following which has come from a form:

```
ColA (UniqID)       ColB
41447.9162847222    Name1, Name2, Name3, Name4
41447.9158912037    Name2, Name6, Name9
```

I would like to end up with:

```
ColA               B
41447.9162847222   Name1
41447.9162847222   Name2
41447.9162847222   Name3
41447.9162847222   Name4
41447.9158912037   Name2
41447.9158912037   Name6
41447.9158912037   Name9
```

I can't use VLOOKUP or MATCH as Names may be duplicated in other records but ColA code will always be unique.

T

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An answer using native spreadsheet functions:

`=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE(REGEXREPLACE(SPLIT(CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(", "&B:B;", ";CHAR(10)&A:A&CHAR(9)));CHAR(10));"(.*?)\t(.*)";{"$1";"$2"})))`

Disadvantage is that all columns are coerced to text strings with this method. There are workarounds for this, but the formula would get even more ridiculous.

---

An answer using a Google Apps Script custom function, which also trims leading and trailing spaces in the comma-separated list, as per the request in comments:

```
function advanceSplit(range1, range2)
{
  var output = [], temp;
  for (var i = 0, length = range1.length; i < length; i++)
  {
    if (range1[i][0])
    {
      var temp = range2[i][0].split(",");
      for (var j = 0, length2 = temp.length; j < length2; j++)
      {
        output.push([range1[i][0], temp[j].trim()]);
      }
    }
  }
  return output;
}
```

and then invoke in a spreadsheet cell:

`=advancedSplit(A:A;B:B)`

My anecdotal observation is that for very large data sets, the latter method (custom function) has better performance than the former.

Comment: The script option works great! If I wanted to add a TRIM option - how or where do I add this in?

Comment: Could you be more specific about what you want to trim?

Comment: Col B - is submitted via a form and gets messy with spaces before or after names - For Example: Name1,Name2,    Name3 ,Name4.  The names are later matched against a spreadsheet with prior student names to see if they are already entered.  I would like to clean off all white space on either side.

Comment: Sorry for the delay. Is the column submitted via checkboxes, or is the user manually entering a comma-separated list?