# Google App Scripts(spreadsheet) - consolidate data into one sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

**Here is the set up**
We have a contest with all employees based on project scores. Each project has two categories of employees(4 employees per category) and two scores(one for each category of employee).
I need to grab all the scores for the employees and output it into a spreadsheet. [The following spreadsheet has misc. columns removed](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1kF0JeIS9mNR1VneNiC8b4__kqRgrQvbcVdTL68wZtTA/edit?usp=sharing)
**Sheet Explanation**
The sheet labeled "Example data" is the source we will be pulling data from

1. We need to match Editor and Editor Score
2. We need to match Webmaster and webmaster score

The sheet labeled "Example output" is what I want to be generated in another spreadsheet named "Contest Result" with the sheet name from the source sheet(They are named by date ranges).

1. We need to compile each employee by the categories
2. We need to compile all scores to the row for a singular employee

I had found this [Removing Duplicates Article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/removing_duplicates) that seemed to at least process the information and compare it in a manner that I think this can be done, but am failing to make it work due to being inexperienced.

Did not know what Transpose was till someone commented :)
Here is the solution in another article for how to pull it off with Google Apps Script and with using the spreadsheet option. 
[How to split and transpose results over 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530499/how-to-split-and-transpose-results-over-2-columns)

Here is the actual code I used to make it work(it is a little horrible but I tried) suggestions on how to improve this?:

```
function createScoreSheet() {

  // Get Source spreadsheet
  var source = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sourceSheet = source.getActiveSheet();
  var SourceActivate = sourceSheet.activate();
  // Set Sheet Name
  var sheetName = sourceSheet.getSheetName();
  // Set Values to transpose and combine
  var sourceEditor = sourceSheet.getRange("C1:C51");
  var sourceWeb = sourceSheet.getRange("D1:D51");
  var editorScores = sourceSheet.getRange("L1:L51");
  var webScores = sourceSheet.getRange("K1:K51");
  // Used to create a new spreadsheet
  var sheetNameNew = sheetName + " Scores";
  var createSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().insertSheet(sheetNameNew,0);
  var targetSheet = source.getSheetByName(sheetNameNew);
  var totalScore = 1;
  // s is the the counter we use to stick values into the rows
  var s = 3;
  // n is the the counter we use to stick values into the columns
  var n = 1;
  // loops through twice, once for the editor values, once for the webmaster
  for (var j = 1; j<3; j++) {
    if (j == 1) {
      // grab values for the editors and copy to new sheet
      sourceEditor.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange("A1"));
      editorScores.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange("B1"));
      // delete the header row then sort the column ASC by default     
      targetSheet.deleteRow(n);
      targetSheet.sort(1);
      // Find the last value to see how many scores we have
      var lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
    }
    if (j == 2) {
      // grab values for the webmasters and copy to new sheet
      sourceWeb.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(n,1));
      webScores.copyTo(targetSheet.getRange(n,2));
      // delete the header row then sort the column ASC by default 
      targetSheet.deleteRow(n);
      lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
      targetSheet.getRange(n,1,lastRow,2).sort(1);
      lastRow = targetSheet.getLastRow();
    }
    // this loop will check to see if the value of the cell is equal to the next on the list and move the score
    for (var i = 1; i<lastRow+1; i++) {
      // Grab the name of the current row and the next
      var firstName = targetSheet.getRange(n,1).getValue();
      var nextName = targetSheet.getRange(n+1,1).getValue();
      // Grab the scores
      var oldScore = targetSheet.getRange(n+1,2);
      var newScore = targetSheet.getRange(n,s);
      // Loop to check to see if the firstname is blank and break to find the next value
      if (firstName === "") {
       break; 
      }
      // checks to see if name is equal to the next then shifts then copies the score and adjust the horizontal position
      if (firstName == nextName) {
        totalScore = oldScore + newScore;
        oldScore.copyTo(newScore);
        s = s+1;
        targetSheet.deleteRow(n+1);
      }
      // resets horizontal position for the score and increases the row 
      else {
        s=3;
        n=n+1;
      }
    }
    // kills remaining rows
    targetSheet.deleteRows(n,37);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it like this:

If you want to generate the names automatically as well, then write this to the output sheet A1:

=unique('Example Data'!B2:B) - This function simply generate the editor names to the A2-A5 cells.

Now write this to the B2 cell:

=transpose(filter('Example Data'!E:E,'Example Data'!B:B=A2)) - This function filters the editor points according to the given name in the beginning of the row (in this case its A2). Then transposes the result in a horizontal form. To get the result for the other rows, simply populate this formula down.

I think you can find out the rest. :)

Hope it helps.