# Parse out concatenate columns into separate rows

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Hi guys im using google app script trying to get the data from google form to transpose from raw data to sorted table. But my code is not working. Im trying to do a custom function. and call for `=columnSplit(A1:B2, 2, ",")`.

This is what i have:

[image: Image One]

the dates all on column A and Concatenate numbers at number B.

```
9/10/17 13:30:00     1234,4567,8910

9/11/17 12:34:00     0987,6543,21
```

what i want to get:

[image: Image Two]

```
9/10/17 13:30:00  1234

9/10/17 13:30:00  4567

9/10/17 13:30:00  8910

9/11/17 12:34:00  0987

9/11/17 12:34:00  6543
```

I took my reference from here: [How to split and transpose results over 2 columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17530499/how-to-split-and-transpose-results-over-2-columns)

```
function columnSplit(reference, index, delimiter) {
  var input = reference;
  var output = [];
  if (input.constructor !== Array) {
    input = [[input]];                     
  }
  for (var i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    var parts = input[i][index - 1].toString().split(delimiter);
    for (var j = 0; j < parts.length; j++) {
      var copy = input[i].slice(0);        
      copy[index - 1] = parts[j].trim();  
      output.push(copy);
    }
  }
  return output
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
function R2C(a1,idx,dlm){
  var vA=a1;
  var oA=[];
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    var tA=vA[i][idx].toString().split(dlm);
    var oidx=(idx==1)?0:1;
    for(k=0;k<tA.length;k++){
      if(idx==0){
        oA.push([tA[k],vA[i][1]]);
      }else{
        oA.push([vA[i][0],tA[k]]);
      }
    }
  }
  return oA;
}
```

These are my spreadsheets which show how to use it:

[image]

[image]

> For this function a1 is a selected range.  idx is either 0 or 1.  dlm is the delimiter.

Comment: This solution is very similar to the one you shared. It just has a couple little differences that make it easier for me to understand.

Comment: Thank you so muchh!! :)) can i ask why sometimes i run the code, i get error: Cannot read property "length" from undefined??

Comment: You might be able to run the code if you provide the A1Notation of the range in first parameter ( perhaps something like (‘Sheet1!A1:B4',0,’,’) and the index of the data array that needs to be split 0 or 1 and the split delimiter. But actually I thought you were going to use it as a cell formula.

Comment: Yes im using the function R2C. It works perfectly even though it shows the error. Just thinking if i can get rid of the error hahhaha. But it's fine for me!